# Cross origin frame error after updating to Edge 98+

Tags: cross-domain, microsoft-edge

Started cross origin frame error after updating to Microsoft Edge 98+. It was working fine with an older version of Edge and also works in all versions of Google Chrome. Also tried to set same value to document.domain in both parent document and iframe loaded document.

**Browser console log:**
[Console error in edge v100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjMk.png)

Any recent change or updating causing this error in edge?. No preflight requests logs in network tab. Does anyone know is it a known issue in edge version 98+ and appreciate if you could share any workaround to resolve?

Comment: I would like to know if the url of the frame with the problem you mentioned is in the same domain as the parent page. If the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is followed correctly but this issue still occurs, I recommend that you can report this problem to relvant team. Just press ` Alt＋Shift+ I` to edit this issue and send it. In addition, you can also try it in Edge Canary to check if this issue still exist.

Comment: @XudongPeng - Thanks for the update. Yes due to security concers I have not shared the complete URL, Yes URL is the same domain(protocal, domain, porat all same) as the parent. Sure will consider to verify in edge canary release.

Comment: Still getting CORS error in latest version of MS Edge. Please share workaround if any one been facing similar issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide specific steps to reproduce this issue. In addition, if this issue only occurs after Edge version 98, I recommend you report this issue to relevant team.

Answer (score 0):

Try To set this:

```
edge://flags
```

find

```
Block scripts loaded via document.write
```

set this to 'disable'